# Include only specific file patterns in meld comparison

Tags: filtering, wildcard, glob, meld

I want to compare directories with Meld, but only specific file patterns.
E.g., only `*.c;*.cc;*.icc;*.h` files.

Meld can use File Filters, but I could only use them for **exclusion** filtering specific file patterns. That approach is not useful for me, I guess.

Can an **inclusion** filter be applied?

I tried with the idea of "double negation": Excluding "everything but `*.c;*.cc;*.icc;*.h`", which in effect would include only those patterns.

I tried using File Filters which worked well for listing "everything but ..." using `ls -d -- <my_filter>` at the command line (see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/397885/137608)). I assume this is a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for any filter to work in Meld.
None of these worked:

1. `!(*.c|*.h|*.cc)`
2. `!(*@(.c|.h|.cc))`
3. `!(*.@(c|h|cc))`

***Note***: I do not mean to use any type of Text Filter, since I do not care at this point about the contents of files, but only about the file names.

***Note*** : I have `bash` and

```
$ shopt extglob
extglob on
```

Comment: According to the Meld documentation, filters are only available for excluding files. Unfortunately you will have to list files to exclude as far as my research has shown. Meld is written in Python and when I dug through the code it was not blatantly obvious where the code was using the file filter as an "excluding" filter, but it might be easy to add a flag to make it use the filter as an "including" filter. Again, I haven't found the specific code that filters the files, so this is only conjecture.

Comment: @mrunion - Since meld does not seem to have the "inclusion" feature explicitly, perhaps it is possible to emulate that (maybe in a limited form). That is why I tried negation+wildcards.